# Stack Overflow API to build commercial apps

Tags: support, api

I want to create a desktop client for Stack Overflow using the APIs available and it will be a **paid app**. So my question is, whether this is allowed or not.

Can I create a software using their APIs for commercial purposes? I went through the terms mentioned in the [Stack Exchange Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service).

Still it is not clear. Any help or reference will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackapps.com/questions/2507/do-i-need-permission-to-use-the-se-api-for-a-commercial-app

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a duplicate of [questions on Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/questions/2507/do-i-need-permission-to-use-the-se-api-for-a-commercial-app) -- which is where API questions really belong anyway, not here.